# The same Webstart JAR, JNLP on diffrerent App Servers ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, websphere, classnotfoundexception, java-web-start, jnlp

I have encountered that issue. I have got fine working webstart on  WebSphere7 server1. I've copied `myapp.jar` and `myapp.jnlp` on another server2.
Only `codebase=` and `<jar href=` was modified.

But I get (Unable to ):

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mypack.swt.EntryPoint
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is JNLP:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://corp.com/webapp/jnlp">
<information>
  <title>My App</title>
  <vendor>Foo</vendor>
  <homepage href="http://corp.com" />
  <description>My App</description>
  <offline-allowed/>
</information>
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
<update check="always" policy="always" />
<resources>
  <j2se version="1.6+" initial-heap-size="512m" max-heap-size="1024m"/>
  <property name="par1" value="val1"/>

  <jar href="http://corp.com/webapp/jnlp/myapp.jar"/>
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="com.mypack.swt.EntryPoint">
</application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

It is a maven project with jar, sign, shade plugins.. I tried to rebuild, but it didn't help..

Could you, please, help me to find correct way to locate the problem..
Thanks.

p.s. one difference I've found is no folder travers on second server2.
p.p.s. It feels like no download occurs, but if I change jar-file name resource not found excpt appears..

**Edit**

I found that downloading the resource jat from second server2 is extremely small - a couple of kBytes against 12mbytes in case with fine working first server1. I have figured out in Java temp file view console.
So... Is it broken jar-resource downing load?

Comment: 1) Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0). 2) Note that `<jar href="http://corp.com/webapp/jnlp/myapp.jar"/>` should be relative to the code base, so `<jar href="myapp.jar"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**

Idea has came to me in the night)

I've analyzed sequence of action when get WebStart.

First you download the .jnlp file. It should be valid and available to downoload. Then, in my case Chrome, suggests action - Open or Save .jnlp file. Then I click open. What's going on - Windows look at the extensions and run file with appropriate exe. This is javaw.exe which parse the .jnlp file and try do download to resource .jar.

But! my .jar **resource file was located on the secured part in the web**! And javaw is unauthorized.

javaw get "401-un-authorized.html" and cannot find any main class in that .html )))
So, that's why I saw very tiny app in java cache!

Thanks guys!

Comment: Can you explain "But! my .jar resource file was located on the secured part in the web! And javaw is unauthorized.

javaw get "401-un-authorized.html" and cannot find any main class in that .html ))) So, that's why I saw very tiny app in java cache" little bit in detail?

Comment: 1) User is unauthorized 2) JNLP is located in the unrestricted area and accessible for this user 3) The source JAR file is located in restricted area 4) JAR cannot be downloaded. user got 1kb stub instead normal jar-file.

Answer (score 0):

Please try clearing the java cache once sometimes if earlier version of jar is present then it wont get downloaded from jnlp webstart. And also check write permissions on server 2 preferably where jar gets downloaded that dir should have write permission.

Comment: Servers are windows. Folder, containing both .jar and .jnlp, is located in the webapp (root). Access rights seems to be ok. It is interesting: I clear java temp files, click jnlp and no "Downloading application" message appears, though, .jar file is 12 Mb.